# Replace all but every nth character in a phrase with "_"

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of JavaScript.
It replaces every consonant in a phrase with `_`.
I need to replace all but 1st and then every 3rd character in every word in a phrase with `_`

So that `Lions in Copenhagen`  becomes `L__n_ i_ C__e__a__`,but I have no idea how to do this.

```
//Replace consonant
var str = document.getElementById("dropped-consonant").innerHTML;
letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (str[i].match(/[QWRTYPSDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]/i)) {
    letters += '<span class="hint">' + '_' + '</span>';
  } else {
    letters += str[i];
  }
}
document.getElementById("dropped-consonant").innerHTML = letters;
```

Comment: Note: since you use the `i` modifier, you don't need both upper and lower case in the regexp.

Comment: @RandyCasburn He's already doing that with `str[i]`.

Comment: `letters = str.replace(/(.)(.{0,2})/g,(_,a,b)=>a+Array.from({length:b.length+1}).join("_"));` :: 'Copenhagen' => 'C__e__a__n'

Comment: What an amazing community you have here. I've just asked this question and was hoping someone would answer tomorrow but instead I get so many reactions in a couple of minutes!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking whether the letter is a consonant, check whether `i` is a multiple of 3 using the modulus operator, as well as whether the input character is a space.

```js
let str = 'Lions in Copenhagen';
let letters = '';
for (var i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
  if (i % 3 != 0 && str[i] != ' ') {
    letters += '<span class="hint">_</span>';
  } else {
    letters += str[i];
  }
}

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = letters;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I used a wrong example at first. Will this still work with an updated one: "So that Lions in Copenhagen becomes L__n_ i_ C__e__a__"

Comment: Why would it make a difference? The algorithm doesn't depend on the example.

Comment: Oh, you need to check for spaces.

Comment: Yes, exactly, couldn't formulate it clearly

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good candidate for modulo.

```
if (i % 3 == 0) {
    // add str[i]
} else {
    // add _
}
```

Comment: Why `i == 1`? The first character is `i == 0`.

Comment: @Barmar ... of cause it is, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can let the Regular Expression do the magic:

```js
const generatedString = "Lions in Copenhagen".replace(/(.{1})([\w\s]{2})/g, (match, keptChar, repalcableGroup) => keptChar + repalcableGroup.replace(/\w/g, '_'));    


console.log(generatedString);
```

`/(.{1})([\w\s]{2})/` this will help you to get the matches ( each 3 characters, including spaces )
each match contains two captured groups, the first one is the character to keep, and the second group is the 2 characters that we need to replace with `_`

then for each match, we return the same, but first we do the replacement of the second group, but not for spaces `repalcableGroup.replace(/\w/g, '_'))`